# How do I expand XML tags with a regex replacement

Tags: regex, xml

I have a service which delivers an empty XML document for me to fill. However, because in that document the element content is empty, these element tags are written in the shortened form. To be able to fill in the values I have to expand the tags to an opening and a closing tag. Is it possible to do this with a regulax expression replacement?

Comment: what language / program are you working in? -- can help with the regex, but not the replacement part without more info

Comment: I am using it for XML messages in SOAP UI.

Comment: You should be using regex on xml or html.  There are much better methods using the xml and html classes.  Xml and Html are not regular and is much more difficult with regex.  Xml Linq is usually very simple to add tags, delete tags, and modify values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following regex pattern to detect compacted XML elements and replace them with the expanded version:

```
<([^\s>]+)([^<>]*)(\/>)
```

And the replace template looks like this:

```
<$1$2></$1>
```

The mechanism is rather straigtforward. The first group **([^\s>]+)** detects the XML element name. The second group **([^<>]*)** detects all attributes and namespaces (if applicable) and the last group **(/>)** detects the closing mark for compacted elements.

```
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
```

Translates into:

```
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod>
```

Comment: Nice and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

While your answer was almost correct, it doesn't take into account a couple of possibilities.

firstly, if all of the elements are not separated by a new line, then your regex will match the whole line, to counterract this, it needs to be made lazy,l like so:

```
<(.*?)\/>
```

this means it will match the shortest possible expression between < and />

then, we have the problem that it will match any number of normal elements, followed by an empty one, such as:

```
<test1></test1></test2/>
```

because it still matches everything between the first < and the next />

So we need to use a negative lookahead, so it only matches an element that does NOT contain another > -- like so:

```
<((.(?!>))*?)\/>
```

then your first capture group should still contain the name of the element you want to replace with

```
<$1><\/$1>
```

WARNING: if any of the elements contain attributes, then they will be included in the closing tag, and this won't work either.

Comment: oh - also the match all '.' doesn't need to be made lazy after the negative lookahead has been added in, so <((.(?!>))*)\/> should suffice

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is possible.

Use this regex to search:

```
<(.*)\/>
```

And this regex to replace:

```
<$1><\/$1>
```

Comment: this will not work: this will match everything between the first opening '<', and the last '/>'

Comment: In my usecase I have just one tag per line, so I did not encounter that problem.

Comment: ahh - it would be helpful when asking a question if you included some source code, so that we could see what it is you are working with - especially in the case of helping to write regular expressions.